# create, add, filter,search by tag strategy in mvc 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I 'm working on my first blog website, have most of the functionality working and now i need to implement this kind of feature - working with tags. 
Here is the drill:

I have two classes which have a field `tags`, i will remove most of the fields to save your time:

```
 public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
 public class Video
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
    }
```

When I'm creating each of the objects, i can give tag a name. For example "sci-fi news", "world economy", "interesting stuff" and so on. So idea is that every time i create a tag with new name it being added to index page as a list and when i click one of them it gives a list of all news with the same tags. Which already stored in db.

I was thinking to use anchored Names in Action links, is that correct direction? Do i work with db and sort it on db level, or i create a list of items and go through it? What is the best, easiest way to approach this? If possible, could you please direct me to similar example. Thank you

Comment: you can search the record from db by tag. that is good approach. you will get all the records which contains that tag.

Comment: Could you please direct me to such an example?